# PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor utility

Tags: java, spring, exception

I've found on the Internet many references about the use of PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor bean.

But its use is still too dark for me, I've searched for explanations with no success... can someone explain to me what is the utility of this bean?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found more information about this class.

I fact it is used to translate all errors generated during the persistence process (HibernateExceptions, PersistenceExceptions...) into DataAccessException objects.